# you may need an appropriate loader to load this file on windows with webpack not in linux and mac os

Tags: webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to write a webpack file that will create a project in reactjs with es6 support. Here is my webpack.config.js

```
webpackConfig = {
    /*entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'),
        filename: 'build.js'
    },*/
    entry: { 
        lite: "./lite.js", pro: "./pro.js",
    },
    output: { filename: "dist/[name].js" },
    plugins: [ 
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin("dist/init.js"),
        new WebpackNotifierPlugin({alwaysNotify: true, title: 'Webpack'})
     ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: __dirname + '/src',
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react','es2015']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader?modules')
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                loader: "style!css!less"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                loaders: [
                    'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
                    'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
                ]
            }
            // { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
        ]
    }
};
```

Here is my .babelrc file

```
{
  "presets" : ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

It runs on mac os and linux but having a problem when i try to run it in windows. any explanation for that error?? It is weird.

Here is the error

```
ERROR in ./src/lite.js
Module parse failed: C:\xampp\htdocs\ONLINE\CF7\cf7visualPlugin\wp-content\plugins\cf7s                           kins-visual\src\lite.js Unexpected token (9:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (9:12)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (C:\xampp\htdocs\ONLINE\CF7\cf7visualPlugin\wp-content\plugins                           \cf7skins-visual\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (C:\xampp\htdocs\ONLINE\CF7\cf7visualPlugin\wp-content\plug                           ins\cf7skins-visual\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (C:\xampp\htdocs\ONLINE\CF7\cf7visualPlugin\wp-content                           \plugins\cf7skins-visual\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1822:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (C:\xampp\htdocs\ONLINE\CF7\cf7visualPlugin\wp-c                           ontent\plugins\cf7skins-visual\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:17                           15:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (C:\xampp\htdocs\ONLINE\CF7\cf7visualPlugin\wp-conte                           nt\plugins\cf7skins-visual\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1692:1                           9)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (C:\xampp\htdocs\ONLINE\CF7\cf7visualPlugin\wp-content\                           plugins\cf7skins-visual\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (C:\xampp\htdocs\ONLINE\CF7\cf7visualPlugin\wp                           -content\plugins\cf7skins-visual\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:                           1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (C:\xampp\htdocs\ONLINE\CF7\cf7visualPlugin\wp-cont                           ent\plugins\cf7skins-visual\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1597:                           21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (C:\xampp\htdocs\ONLINE\CF7\cf7vi                           sualPlugin\wp-content\plugins\cf7skins-visual\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\d                           ist\acorn.js:1861:32)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (C:\xampp\htdocs\ONLINE\CF7\cf7visualPlugin\wp-content                           \plugins\cf7skins-visual\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1796:19)
 @ ./lite.js 2:0-24
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this line:

include: __dirname + '/src',

to this:

exclude: /node_modules/,

Comment: there is a exclude already. did you meant that include: path.join('_dirname','/src')

Comment: Ah, you're right. I suggest removing the include and leaving just the exclude.

Answer (score 1):

it worked for me by changing

```
include: __dirname + '/src',
```

to

```
include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
```